# How to compute the time complexity for a recurrence relationship?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have to compute the time complexity for this recurrence relationship:

T(n) = \begin{cases} c1, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ = 1} \\ 8T(n/4) +n +c2, & \mbox{if } n\mbox{ > 1} \end{cases}

Can someone please show me how to do it using substitution method?  
I know the final result but I don't know the steps of getting to it.

The result should be:  \begin{array}{rcl} O(n^\frac{3}{2} ) \end{array}

Thank you!!

Comment: Here's a sketch. Try $T(n)=n^k$. $n^k = 8 (n/4)^k$, then $8=4^k$, and $k=3/2$.

Comment: If $4 \nmid n$, how is your definition to be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let n be a power of 4 say n = 4^i then substitute this expression in the recurrence relation and use repeated substitution.